# How to convert object to array format using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am getting Json object from backend like below format.

```
{
"Day-Workers": {
    "0": {
        "Peter": {
            "id": "EJ6609",
            "Sal": "$1000"
        }
    },
    "1": {
        "Sat": {
            "id": "Ej6610",
            "Sal": "$1200"
        }
    }
}}
```

But I want to convert this object to array of objects format like below.

```
{
"Day-Workers": [{
        "Peter": {
            "id": "EJ6609",
            "Sal": "$1000"
        }
    },

    {
        "sat": {
            "id": "Ej6610",
            "Sal": "$1200"
        }
    }
]}
```

Is there way to implement to convert this format, Thanks.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Fix the backend code to return an array instead of an object with numeric keys

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
obj["Day-Workers"] = Object.values(obj["Day-Workers"]);
```

```js
var obj = 
{
"Day-Workers": {
    "0": {
        "Peter": {
            "id": "EJ6609",
            "Sal": "$1000"
        }
    },
    "1": {
        "Sat": {
            "id": "Ej6610",
            "Sal": "$1200"
        }
    }
}}

obj["Day-Workers"] = Object.values(obj["Day-Workers"]);
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: But the key is not static it will change dynamically and added data also.